# How to test single Codeception class or method with PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, codeception

Is there any option to test a single Codeception class or method with PhpStorm/PHPUnit?

I know how to to run Test/TestCase with plain .php/PHPUnit files.

**But how do I configure PhpStorm to work with Codeception?**

Comment: Well ... PhpStorm still does not have Codeception tests integration .. so I guess there is no easy way of doing this. Please vote .. and maybe... one day ... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16350

Answer (score 1):

You could give https://github.com/tsari/docker-xdebug-phpstorm a try.
That's a shell script which will be used as external tool in phpstorm and allows you to run or debug single methods, files, directories or all tests at once.

Currently it works only with docker. But you could fork and extend it. ;)